# How to set input time limit for user in game?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering how I can make a program with input of MAXIMUM 5 seconds(e.g he can send input after 2 seconds) in python I decided to do a SIMPLE game where you basically have to rewrite a word below 5 seconds. I know how to create input and make it wait EXACTLY 5 SECONDS, but what I want to achieve is to set maximum time of input to 5 seconds so if a user types an answer in let's say 2 seconds he will go the next word. Could you tell me the way to achieve my goal. Thanks in advance!

```
for word in ["banana","earth","turtle","manchester","coctail","chicken"]:

    # User gets maximum of 5 seconds to write the word,
    # if he does it before 5 seconds pass ,he goes to next word (does not have to wait exactly 5 seconds, he   
    # can send input in e.g 2 seconds)      
    # if he does not do it in 5 seconds he loses game and it is finished


    user_input = input(f"Type word '{word}': ")

    #IF the word is correct go to next iteration
    if(user_input==word):
        continue

    #If the word is incorrect finish the game
    else:
        print("You lost")
        break
```

## I tried to do it with threading.Timer() but it doesn't work

```
import threading

class NoTime(Exception):
    pass

def count_time():
    raise NoTime

for word in ["banana","earth","turtle","manchester","coctail","chicken"]:
    try:


        #Create timer which raises exception after 5 seconds
        timer = threading.Timer(5,count_time)
        timer.start()

        user_input = input(f"Type word '{word}': ")
        #if timer hasn't lasted 5 seconds then destroy it in order to prevent unwanted exception
        timer.cancel()

        if user_input==word:
            print("Correct")
        else:
            print("Incorrect, you LOSE!")
            break

    except NoTime:
        print("You run out of time, you lose")
        break
```

## The error i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\papit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\papit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1394, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\papit\OneDrive\Pulpit\Programming\Python Bro Course\Math\second\threading_training.py", line 7, in count_time
    raise NoTime
NoTime
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import threading

def lost():
    print("You run out of time, you lose")


for word in ["banana", "earth", "turtle", "manchester", "coctail", "chicken"]:

    timer = threading.Timer(5, lost)
    timer.start()

    user_input = input(f"Type word '{word}': ")
    timer.cancel()

    if user_input == word:
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Incorrect, you LOSE!")
```

Comment: Thanks for effort but it's not what I meant. In your example after 5 seconds I am still inside for loop and I still have to finish submitting input. If I am not fast enough to write a word in 5 seconds I should exit the loop